# How to parameterize selector for copy artifacts in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

We're heavily using pipeline jobs in our Jenkins system and need to be able to parameterize the `copyArtifacts` step using the `Build selector for Copy Artifact` job parameter.

In the first place I found that - while the parameter returns a `String` - the `copyArtifacts` step required an instance of `BuildSelector`.

I found the `BuildSelectorParameter.getSelectorFromXml` method to convert the parameter into an instance of `BuildSelector` like:

```
properties([parameters([
    [$class: 'BuildSelectorParameter',
    defaultSelector: upstream(fallbackToLastSuccessful: true),
    description: '',
    name: 'copyArtifactSelector']])
])

@NonCPS
static BuildSelector getSelectorFromParam(String xmlText) {
    BuildSelectorParameter.getSelectorFromXml(xmlText)
}

node {
    def selector = getSelectorFromParam(params.copyArtifactSelector)
    copyArtifacts(
            projectName: 'sourceJob',
            selector: selector
    )
}
```

However I just realized that the `BuildSelector` which is created is not `Serializable`. Therefore I'm getting now the expected exception:

```
hudson.plugins.copyartifact.TriggeredBuildSelector
Caused: java.io.NotSerializableException: hudson.plugins.copyartifact.TriggeredBuildSelector
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:860)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
```

After that I tried to check how the copy artifact plugin deals with that - unfurtunately I couldn't find any clue in the source code. Maybe it only works by chance? The methods to create a `BuildSelector` do not seem to create any kind of serializable class.

But maybe someone already came accross this issue and has a hint?

### Edit

What I found so far:

- If I store the `BuildSelector` object in some variable it'll throw me the `NotSerializableException`.
- However if I do not pass it to some variable first but do the call in the method call to `copyArtifacts` the `NotSerializableException` will not occur - at least not for now:

  ```
  node {
      copyArtifacts(
              projectName: 'sourceJob',
              selector: getSelectorFromParam(params.copyArtifactSelector)
      )
  }
  ```

### Thoughts

Is there probably even a hidden bug in the Copy Artifact plugin which could cause `NotSerializableException` exceptions to occur - or am I missing something?

### Question

Is it safe to use my `getSelectorFromParam` method like done in the updated example? If it is not safe, is there a safe solution?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had the same issue after spending a good few hours on this I found this and it worked perfectly for me.

The name of **Build selector for Copy Artifact** job parameter here is *copyArtifactSelector* and up stream job name here is *sourceJob*:

```
    copyArtifacts(projectName: 'sourceJob',
                  selector: [$class: 'ParameterizedBuildSelector', 
                             parameterName: 'copyArtifactSelector'] );
```

Note : plugin="copyartifact@1.39.1"

EDIT:
In the meantime - using `copyartifact` V1.43 - the following syntax is supported:

```
    copyArtifacts(projectName: 'sourceJob',
                  selector: buildParameter('copyArtifactSelector'));
```

Comment: After re-reading your answer I now fully understand the difference between my approach and your solution. Took me some time to figure it out. Thanks for saving myself some more headaches.

Answer (score 3):

Little off-topic, but if you want to use the parameter from an Upstream-triggered Pipeline Job (for example directly from 'sourceJob'), you could use the following:

```
steps {
    build
        job: 'downstream-copyartifacts-parametrized-job',
        propagate: false,
        wait: false,
        parameters: [
            [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'copyArtifactSelector', value: "<TriggeredBuildSelector />"]
        ]
}
```

In this example the artifacts from the upstream job will be used by `TriggeredBuildSelector`. This can be useful, if you want to trigger a second subsequent job that uses artifacts generated by the 'sourceJob'. The parameter definition in 'downstream-copyartifacts-parametrized-job' can then look like this:

```
parameters {
    buildSelector(
        name: 'copyArtifactSelector',
        defaultSelector: lastSuccessful(),
        description: 'A build to take the artifacts from'
    )
}
```

And the usage of the build parameter in a pipeline can be similar as stated above:

```
steps {
    copyArtifacts
        filter: "/some/artifact/to/copy.zip",
        fingerprintArtifacts: true,
        projectName: 'sourceJob',  
        selector: buildParameter('copyArtifactSelector')
}
```

I hope someone finds this useful.

Comment: Thanks for that. What would be really great is to have one option to forward all the parameters of the current build to the downstream - much like with the paramterized trigger plugin for the Freestyle jobs. However I supposed this should be seperate question...

Comment: How can I define buildSelector as en environment variable instead of parameters?
Ie env.selector = new buildSelector(upstreamBuild())?
I have tried few syntaxes but I am still confuses what works where in pipelines.

WorkflowScript: 64: unable to resolve class buildSelector 
 @ line 64, column 31.
                       def abc = new buildSelector(upstreamBuild())